# Can not save changes into SharedPreferences

Tags: android

I want to save some data into `SharedPreferences`. everything is intact. I can read from it but I can not save anything.

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("preferences", 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putInt("age", 25);
editor.putString("name", "name1");
editor.commit();
```

I have checked everything many times. any suggestion ?

EDIT: I solved it by using this line:

```
SharedPreferences Prefs = PreferenceManager
        .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

Comment: Could you also post the snippet where do you retrieve the values?

Comment: @I kinda found it.its working now. check my edit. it was the name of preferences.but to clarify it better, what exactly should I use as the "name"? the name of preference file without the XML ?

Comment: @Shervin if you've fixed your problem it is okay (and even desirable) for you to make an answer to it and accept your own answer as the solution, not just editing the answer into the question (indeed, this is not a good thing to do)

Comment: SharedPreferences stores values inside an xml file and "name" is the name of that xml file. Delete this question if you can, since it is  going to help nobody

Comment: @blackbelt I used the exact name as the xml file, but it was not working.

Comment: without have a look to the code it's impossible to understand what was happening

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to add `.apply();` after any change. So for example the

```
editor.putInt("age", 25);
```

would change to

```
editor.putInt("age", 25).apply();
```

Comment: Shervin is calling commit, apply should not be necessary

Comment: Missed that. Darn these faulty eyes of mine.

Comment: @ArmaAK hows that different from .commit() ?